# filter mutidimensionnal array using typeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter an array using more than one filter. But so far I haven't succeeded to get what I am expecting.

this is my component Angular

```js
list = [ {type: type1, code: code1}, {type: type2, code: code2}]

searchElement(code?: string, type?: string){
var myVar = this.list

if(type)
myVar = myVar.filter(elt => elt.type.indexOf(type) > -1);

if(code)
myVar = myVar.filter(elt => elt.type.indexOf(code) > -1);

//call another function myFunction() with the filtered array myVar
}
```

Because of the asynchronous Behavior `myFunction()` is called before myVar is filtered. How can I make sure that myVar is filtered before calling `myFunction()`?

Comment: When asking for help, please be sure to format/indent your code in a reasonable, consistent way to make it easier for the people helping you to read it. (It's also really useful to just always do that, so it's easier for *you* to read it.)

Comment: Side note: That's not a multi-dimensional array. It's an array of objects. (Technically, JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays, e.g. `[ [], [], [] ]`; people tend to think of them as multi-dimensional arrays. But this is an array of objects rather than an array of arrays, so not at all like an MD array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both filter values in *one* `filter` callback, rather than using multiple `filter` calls:

```
list = [ {type: type1, code: code1}, {type: type2, code: code2}];

searchElement(code?: string, type?: string){
    var myVar = this.list;

    if (type || code) {
        myVar = myVar.filter(elt => (!type || elt.type.indexOf(type) > -1) && (!code || elt.code.indexOf(code) > -1));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice how each condition is in the form `!filterValue || useTheFilterValue` so that if there is no filter value, that condition is satisfied, and if there is, it's only satisfied if the filter matches.

I've assumed an "and" match is required, which is why I joined the two filtering checks with `&&`. E.g., if you supply both `type` and `code`, I assume both must match in order to keep an element in the array.

(Also, you were checking `code` against `elt.type` instead of `elt.code`.)